# Regular expression to match XML start node but not self-closing nodes, with capability to match some informal syntax typos

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match XML start nodes like the following,

1. normal cases `<ref>` and `<ref name="gbtribune.files.wordpress.com">`
2. empty attribute `<ref name="gbtribune.files.wordpress.com" name2>` or `<ref name="gbtribune.files.wordpress.com" name2= >`
3. missing quotes
   `<ref name=gbtribune.files.wordpress.com>` or `<ref name="gbtribune.files.wordpress.com>` or `<ref name=gbtribune.files.wordpress.com">`

but I do not want it to match a self-closing nodes
`<ref/>` or
`<ref name=gbtribune.files.wordpress.com" />`

I also want the first group to capture the tag name, and the second group to capture all key-value attribute pairs.

My regex is designed as

> `<([a-zA-Z]+)\s*([^\/<>"=\s]+=?(?:(?:"(?:[^<>"]*)"?)|(?:[^=<>"\s]*"?))?\s*)*>`

You can open it here https://regex101.com/r/TVwye1/3

[image]

It works for case 1,2,3, but it also matches the a self-closing nodes. Need help to exclude the self-closing nodes from the matches.

Comment: Why not using a XML parser? Regex aren't the best choice for xml/html parsing, since they aren't regular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Cid I tested some of the top solutions in the previous question, none of them work for my case.

Comment: @Cid My application only allows for using regular expressions.

Comment: Add `(?!.*\/>$)` at the start of the [expression](https://regex101.com/r/TVwye1/4)?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Thanks for the help! It still has problem of making correct matches in strings like `<ref name="gbtribune.files.wordpress.com">txt</ref> <ref/>`. The non-self-closing node in this example cannot be matched.

Comment: Your name portion is missing some [allowed characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
<(?![^<>]*\/\s*>)([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\s+[^\/<>"=\s]+(?:=(?:"[^<>"]*"?|[^=<>"\s]*"?)?)?)*>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/43xUzV/1)

**Details**

- `<` - `<` char
- `(?![^<>]*\/\s*>)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if after the current location, there are any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` followed with `/`, 0+ whitespaces and `>`
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 1: one or more ASCII letters
- `(?:\s+[^\/<>"=\s]+(?:=(?:"[^<>"]*"?|[^=<>"\s]*"?)?)?)*` - 0 or more repetitions of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[^\/<>"=\s]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`, `<`, `>`, `"`, `=` and whitespace
  - `(?:=(?:"[^<>"]*"?|[^=<>"\s]*"?)?)?` - an optional sequence of:
  - `=` - an equal sign
  - `(?:"[^<>"]*"?|[^=<>"\s]*"?)?` - an optional sequence of:

    - `"[^<>"]*"?|` - 0 or more chars other than `<`, `>`, `"` and then an optional `"` or
    - `[^=<>"\s]*"?` - 0 or more chars other than `=`, `<`, `>`, `"` and whitespace and then an optional `"`
- `>` - a `>` char.